# Is my ISP blocking incoming connections to my OpenVPN Server?

Tags: routing, firewall, openvpn, isp, pfsense

I have worked on this for a couple of weeks now, but I don't seem to make progress.

I have a hardware pfsense set up as my Internet router, everything works fine except that I can't connect to the OpenVPN server running on the pfsense.

Before setting the pfsense as router, I put it behind my old router, which acted as fake-wan and tested my VPN setup - I was able to connect. But I can get it to work in my ISP network.

I have tried (in this sequence):

- UDP incoming port 1195
- UDP incoming port 1194
- TCP incoming port 1194
- TCP incoming port 443

Nothings seems to work - tcpdump is not showing anything on these ports coming in:
`tcpdump -lnni igb0 port 1194 and src host xxx.76.19.66` (the remote IP I am connecting with)

My configuration on the pfsense follows the official guide and wizard setup:

- Server mode is Remote Access (SSL/TLS + User Auth)
- TLS Key setup
- Certificates tested & setup
- IPv4 Tunnel Network: 10.0.8.0/24
- IPv4 Local network(s): 192.168.10.0/24

My Firewall rules:
[image]

The public IP of the server is different than the one that is detected on the WAN port of the pfsense: 172.18.36.162 - this is my local IP internal to the ISP.

Any idea how I could further troubleshoot? I called the ISP, but they're not telling me anything. It's a small ISP and I am not even sure they're blocking anything on purpose.

Here is what nmap is telling me:

```bsh
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-24 09:34 W. Europe Standard Time
Nmap scan report for 24.347.74.101
Host is up (0.00s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
1194/tcp filtered openvpn

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.89 seconds
```

(ip replaced by random numbers)

This should show up in packet capture of pfsense, right?

Comment: Firewall seems fine, but have you [forwarded the port](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/nat/forwarding-ports-with-pfsense.html)?

Comment: Yes, I've basically followed the netgate guide [here](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/vpn/openvpn/openvpn-remote-access-server.html#verifying-the-setup) and my NAT+WAN Firewall settings look exactly like shown.

Comment: Okay, a filtered port means something is preventing the probes reaching the port although this isn't necessarily a problem - my OpenVPN server shows the same but I can connect to it fine. 'Filtered' would explain why it isn't showing up in packet capture. Might be worth setting up the OpenVPN server on pfSense to use TCP port 443 as that will *definitely* not be blocked by your ISP, so you could then rule that out as the issue. If you use nmap inside your network you should see the OpenVPN port as 'open'.

Comment: I believe I am behind a CG-NAT (carrier grade nat), which would prevent any incoming connections to reach my pfsense/open vpn server. I will call my ISP again and see if IP v6 will get me a true public IP address.

Also: I had to leave my server today and won't be back until 4 more weeks, then I'll try your suggestion! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but to provide an answer here. It is obvious if you look at the IP that I am assigned by my carrier: `172.18.36.162`

The subnet `172.16.0.0` is part of the [private IP address block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks).

> Various Registries (Maintained by ARIN). 172.16.0.0/12 (172.16.0.0–172.31.255.255) reserved for private networks (RFC 1918).

This means my carrier has an internal network (and firewall), all channelled through a single public IP address. This is called a CG-NAT (carrier grade nat).

In such a setup, it is not possible to get OpenVPN working without changing the Firewall rules of the carrier.

I called them, they offered to provide me a public, static IP address for 5 USD / month. Everything worked from there on.